# Have trouble designing antenna coil for chip receiver

Tags: antenna, coil, rfid, receiver

I'm trying to wind a 125khz rectangle coil antenna for the [AS3933](http://www1.futureelectronics.com/doc/AUSTRIAMICROSYSTEMS/AS3933-BQFT.pdf) receiver chip. I calculated inductance using [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/rectangle-loop-inductance-calculator/) calculator where parameters were:

- Loop Width:20cm
- Loop Height:14.5cm
- Wire Diameter:0.51mm
- Number of Turns:31
- Air Permeability:1 since I was using an empty wooden box to wrap my wire around.

With those parameters I got inductance of 758uH.

Then to tune coil for 125khz, I calculated capacitor value using [this](https://goodcalculators.com/resonant-frequency-calculator/) calculator, and arrived value of 2200pf. 
So I started wrapping my gauge AWG24 wire around empty wooden box 31 times and then connected two ends of the wire in parallel with 2200pf capacitor on the breadboard. Then I connected AS3933's antenna pin LFP1 and antenna ground pin LFN to the breadboard to test functionality.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

**After connecting everything I tried running this code:**

```
Serial.begin(9600);

Serial.println("test1: Checking AS3933 functionality");

if(!asTag.begin(125000))

{

Serial.println("Communication with AS3933 fails.");

return;

}

unsigned long ant1freqOsc= asTag.antennaTuning(1);

if(ant1freqOsc<124000 || ant1freqOsc>126000)

{

Serial.println("Calibration for antenna 1 fails");

return;

}
```

Time after time I got 'Calibration for antenna 1 fails error', as AS3933 can't seem to recognize my antenna coil. Does anyone have possible suggestions on where the problem is?

Is it because the AWG24 wire doesn't connect to breadboard?

Maybe it’s my antenna form.  How close should layers be to one another? Or maybe it is because antenna isn't exactly 125kHz, it's somewhere around 123kHz but it's in the ball park and AS3933 supports that frequency as well, so I'm a little confused. Anyways, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What's under your table? The coil should be far from conducting materials. Have you already tried to elevate it or to turn its axis horizontal? I cannot see any operating voltage decoupling capacitors near the IC, Where are  those parts which cannot be further than few millimeters away from the IC?

Comment: @user287001  I checked there is nothing conductive under my wooden table. You can see 2200pf yellow capacitor on pin 10 and 9, should it be located closer? My arduino provides 3.3v to VCC pin so I dont believe decoupling capacitors*  are necessary?

Comment: Decoupling caps are essential for nearly all ICs to avoid unpredictable behaviour. Your power supply wires are inductors. Decoupling capacitors neutralize their effect. BTW have you programmed OFF the need of 2 more resonators?

Comment: @user287001 I believe I have. I’m going to add decoupling capacitors to the circuit. Maybe problem does something to do with antenna form, the way it was wound? I didn’t stack layers perfectly atop each other, could that be a problem too?

Comment: _"Is it because the AWG24 wire doesn't connect to breadboard?"_ - Perhaps. Did you remove  the insulation from the ends of the wires? Even if you did the wire diameter may be too small to make good contact. Test the coil resistance with a multimeter connected to the adapter board. It should only be a few Ohms.

Comment: measure the inductance or more preferably the real resonant frequency. No inductance calculation formulas are accurate, you can easily have so much error that the internal fine tuning range isn't enough. 2200pF capacitor, too can easily have too much error.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I’ll check the resistance with multimeter and say the results

Comment: @user287001 I’ll have to get some capacitors and miltimeter from the lab and then I’ll add decoupling capacitors and measure inductance. I’ll report my results

Comment: Your windings should lay right next to each other, as neatly as possible.  No gaps, or overlap between loops.  A hand made coil can easily be 20% (or more) off from the calculated value.  Measure the inductor and see.

Comment: The capacitor should be soldered to the coil, right up close to it.

Comment: @JRE I'm using a breadboard so since soldering on PCB board is not an option should I connect capacitor to pins right next to the coil?

Comment: you can check the resonant frequency of your coil just by hooking a signal generator up to it and slowly sweeping through the frequency range and watch for where the peak gets highest due to a standing wave.